# библиотека zip4j. Не открывается зип архив на маке, на виндоус все работает

Tags: java, ziparchive

Пишу архиватор, использую zip4j. Архив создается, файл в него помещается, архив паролируется. При вводе неверного пароля предлагает ввести еще раз, при верном пароле получаю следующее:[image]

вот код класса архиватора:

```
    public class Zipper {
    public void pack() throws IOException {
        ZipParameters zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
        zipParameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
        zipParameters.setEncryptionMethod(EncryptionMethod.AES);
        zipParameters.setAesKeyStrength(AesKeyStrength.KEY_STRENGTH_256);

        File file = new File("/Users/axionlogvinov/Desktop/file.txt");
        file.createNewFile();

        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("/Users/axionlogvinov/main_file.zip", "password".toCharArray());
        zipFile.addFile(file, zipParameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Отладка:

> Код, который вы предоставили,
> выглядит корректным, но стоит проверить, есть ли какие-либо
> предупреждения или исключения, которые могут быть выданы в течение
> процесса создания ZIP-файла.

Для отладки можно добавить логирование исключений:

```
try {
    // ваш код для создания архива
} catch (ZipException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Формат шифрования:

> Если файл успешно распаковывается через командную строку или с помощью
> сторонних программ, проблема может быть в том, что встроенный
> архиватор macOS не поддерживает используемый формат шифрования. Такое
> шифрование, как AES-256, не всегда поддерживается всеми архиваторами
> по умолчанию.

Перекрёстное тестирование:

> Попробуйте создать несколько архивов с разными настройками шифрования
> и без шифрования, чтобы увидеть, возникает ли проблема с распаковкой
> архивов без шифрования. Если нет, точно проблема в совместимости
> шифрования.